# Add padding to table_calendar packaget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add some spacing in the highlighted area

[image]

or in other words **padding to the right, left and bottom of the table_calendar**

I tried cellMargin and rowHeight, but that's not what i want!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class MainCalender extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainCalender({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainCalender> createState() => _MainCalenderState();
}

class _MainCalenderState extends State<MainCalender> {
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 2);
  DateTime? _selectedDay;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121212),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 15,
              horizontal: 12,
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF1f1f1f), width: 3),
            ),
            child: TableCalendar(
              focusedDay: _focusedDay,
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 1),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 30),
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              currentDay: DateTime.utc(2022, 9, 1),
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                cellMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: const Color(0xFF0F9EFF),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
                outsideDaysVisible: true,
                outsideTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
                rowDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF1f1f1f),
                ),
                defaultDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color(0xFF616161),
                  ),
                ),
                weekendDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color(0xFF616161),
                  ),
                ),
                defaultTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
                weekendTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                disabledTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white38),
              ),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                titleCentered: true,
                titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
                formatButtonVisible: false,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xFF1f1f1f),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                leftChevronIcon: const CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                rightChevronIcon: const CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              daysOfWeekStyle: const DaysOfWeekStyle(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF1f1f1f),
                ),
                weekdayStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                ),
                weekendStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                ),
              ),
              selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
              },
              onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedDay = selectedDay;
                    _focusedDay =
                        focusedDay; // update `_focusedDay` here as well
                  },
                );
              },
              calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
              onFormatChanged: (format) {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarFormat = format;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ***Note : i am looking to add padding within the calendar and not around it***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.

Add padding to the `TableContainer` and give the **same** `background-color` to both *TableCalendar and it's parent (in this case: Card)*

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `TableCalendar` with `Padding` or `Card` widget.

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Card(
```

or

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8, bottom: 20),
  child: Card(
```

Comment: This gives padding to the whole table-calendar, i was looking to add padding withing it